# Accessing arrays with methods

Tags: java

Hi guys i'm just starting to learn Java, and I wondering how can I access an array that was declared in a method from another method? 
The design look like this:

```
public class Arrays{
  int arraysize = 2;

     public void initializeArray(){
    float array[] = new float[arraySize]; // Declare array  
     }

     public void accessArray(){
     // I want to access the array from this method.
     }
```

}

Comment: Pass the array as an argument

Comment: you cant you have to declare in class level as `arraysize` or pass as an argument

Comment: You've gotten several good answers.  The big thing to remember is that the place where you _declare_ the array object (`float[] array`) doesn't have to be the same place where the array object is _created_ (with `new`).  See DonaldAnderson's and free3dom's answers for examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about scope of variables in java. This is link I could find on quick Google search. http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

You can declare the array at class level then it is accessible in all methods.

```
    public class Arrays {
    int arraysize = 2;
    private float[] array = null;

    public void initializeArray() {
        array = new float[arraySize]; // Declare array
    }

    public void accessArray() {
        // access array here.
    }
}
```

Or You can pass the variables in method.

```
    public class Arrays {
    int arraysize = 2;

    public void initializeArray() {
        float[] array = new float[arraySize]; // Declare array
        accessArray(array);
    }

    public void accessArray(float[] array) {
        // access array here.
    }
}
```

Given the amount of information, I have from question, approach 1 seems better than 2.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your declaration to make it a member, otherwise it will go out of scope once the `initializeArray` call ends. Then you can access the array from both methods. Try this:

```
public class Arrays{
   float[] array;
   int arraysize = 2;

   public void initializeArray(){
      array = new float[arraySize];   // Declare array  
   }

   public void accessArray(){
      array[0] = 1.0f;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is done thusly

```
public class myClass{
  int arraysize = 2;
  float[] myArray; // Declare array

  public myClass(){
    myArray = new float[arraySize]; // initialize array 
  }

  public float[] accessArray(){
    return myArray;
  }
}
```

The array declaration must not be done inside the class methods.
Variable declaration done inside a method limits it's scope of a variable to the method. (i.e you can't use it anywhere else).

The array is then instantiated in a constructor.
A constructor is a special function that is run when a class is instantiated. 
Constructor are used to instantiated a class's variables
Constructors have the same name as their class and must not specify a return type (so no public int or public void just public)

Next you need to change the return type of the accessArray method. A return type of void states that the method isn't going to return anything. Change it to float[]
Then your accessArray method need only return the array variable.

EDIT: The 
    "return myArray;" 
line of code gives a reference to the array to what ever called the function (Not a copy of the array, the actual array, a quick of Java is that it always does this except when returning primitive data types where it returns a copy)

If you want accessArray() to set floats in the array instead of returning the array it should be implmented like this.

```
public void accessArray(int index, float value){
  myArray[index] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There a two options:

- You declare that array as instance variable

```java
public class Arrays {

    private int arraySize = 2;
    private float array[];// Declare array

    public void initializeArray() {
        array = new float[arraySize];
    }

    public void accessArray() {
        // I want to access the array from this method.
        float first = array[0];
    }
}
```

- You pass the array as parameter to the method (resp. the `initializeArray` method should return an array)

```java
public class Arrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arraySize = 2;
        float[] array = initializeArray(arraySize);
        accessArray(array);
    }

    public static float[] initializeArray(int size) {
        return new float[size];
    }

    public static void accessArray(float[] floats) {
        // I want to access the array from this method.
        float first = floats[0];
    }
}
```